# rosls and roscd still missing

Tags: ros, roscd, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just installed ros-hydro on Ubuntu 12.10 following the tutorial. But when I try to use the command rosls and roscd, it just says command not found. I tried source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash a lot of times and there is "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" in the ~/.bashrc. But rosls and roscd still can't use.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135796/rosls-and-roscd-still-missing/) by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-03-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-05**:
Which package of ROS did you install? The ros-hydro-desktop-full?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-03-05**:
Please link to the tutorial you are following and show the commands you are running.

**Comment by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on 2014-03-06**:
Yes, I install ros-hydro-desktop-full and the like slam-gmapping package.

**Comment by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on 2014-03-06**:
I followed http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/StartGuide

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-06**:
Stupid question: Do you use bash as your shell?

**Comment by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on 2014-03-06**:
echo $SHELL returns "/bin/bash"

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-06**:
What is the output of echo $SHELL

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-06**:
From the information you kindly provided in your other question about the same topic what happens if you do sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosbash?

**Comment by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on 2014-03-06**:
Oh, yes, I works. I did installed the ros-hydro-desktop-full, I can't believe that it is not include rosbash. Thank you very much!!!

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-06**:
Usually, this includes rosbash. Strange. I'll post it as an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Strangely rosbash hasn't been installed.

Run `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosbash`

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on 2014-03-06**:
I have closed the other question. It seems that I didn't install the full version or the install process was interrupted. I wonder if you can give me a list of the packages that I have to install to make my ROS to become a full version.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What happens if you type `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` at the command prompt? Can you then run roscd?

If so, then you should change the location of that line, and move it to the end of your .bashrc file.
It could be the case that the values that are being set by setup.bash are being overwritten by other lines if your bash file.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on 2014-03-06**:
After type source......./setup.bash, and then run roscd, it still returns command not found.

**Comment by [Thomaswang](https://answers.ros.org/users/12811/thomaswang/) on 2014-03-06**:
The line is always at the last line of .bashrc file. Whenever  I cat that file.